# What's causing pool.map() to loop back to the start of main instead of going to the target function in my python script?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script for the shell that does some basic bioinformatic genetic analysis on some sequence data. I've been running this program fine for months but after some recent changes that I cannot track, the `pool.map()` function appears to be going back to the start of `main()` instead of the `processRun()` function I want it to go to.

```
#This is the command thats going to back to the start of `main()`, which is what this is in.
with Pool(numProcessors, maxtasksperchild = maxTasksPerChild) as pool:
  pool.map(processRun, run_list)
```

When I run my code, instead of running through the `processRun()` function, it outputs the intro stuff I have at the beginning of main again, and then keeps infinitely looping back to the beginning again each time it hits the pool call. I researched the multiprocessing module and found something there that might be a potential fix, but when I tried to implement it, it didn't work (probably because I am somehow doing it wrong)

This is the wrong way to do it:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    print('hello')

p = Process(target=foo)
p.start()
```

Instead one should protect the "entry point" of the program by using `if __name__ == '__main__'`: as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support, set_start_method

def foo():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    set_start_method('spawn')
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

This allows the newly spawned Python interpreter to safely import the module and then run the module's `foo()` function.

Similar restrictions apply if a pool or manager is created in the main module.

So I tried to implement it this way, by just wrapping my loop in the function. It didn't work, the same error continued to occur. Please advise on what I'm doing wrong!

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Pool(numProcessors, maxtasksperchild = maxTasksPerChild) as pool:
    pool.map(processRun, run_list)
```

Comment: anything not behind this guard will be repeated. It is generally ok to define methods and constants globals outside the guard but any "work" like even a print call should be behind it.

Comment: Maybe `set_start_method('spawn')` is unnecessary, but I don't know if that would cause this issue or not. Is all the code you've shown the exact same code you are running? Unless there are some odd side effects, or there are some other definitions messing with things, the code you've shown seems to be properly guarding.